# try catch in method containing another method that throws an exception

Tags: c#, methods, try-catch, rethrow

I have a try-catch block in order to handle some methods' exceptions.
This method contains other methods that might throw an exception, like in the example below:

```
try{
 MyMethod(...);

}catch(MyException1){
 // handle it...

}catch(MyException2){
 // handle it...
}



MyMethod(...){
// do things involving 
// MethodThatThrowsException1

// do other things involving
// MethodThatThrowsException2
}


MethodThatThrowsException1(...){
  if(condition1)
      throw MyException1;

  // do something 
}

MethodThatThrowsException2(...){
   if(condition2)
      throw MyException2;

// do something else
}
```

My question is:

can I simply call any method that throw exceptions inside `MyMethod` since I handled them in the first try-catch or should I put a try-catch block (or two) there and rethrow `MyException1`/`MyException2` like this

```
MyMethod(...){
 try{
    // do things involving 
   // MethodThatThrowsException1
 }catch(MyException1){
   rethrow;
 } 

 try{
  // do other things involving
  // MethodThatThrowsException2
  }catch(MyException2){
    rethrow;
  }

}
```

?
 If the shown approach is wrong, can please explain why?

Answer (score 0):

You never need to catch an exception unless you **plan on doing something with it**. Catching an exception and immediately rethrowing it without any other action serves no purpose.

Comment: I planned to do something with it in the first try-catch